# Appending an Existing CSV file via Groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, jde

The following Groovy code can create a new CSV file (in this example testfile.csv) and write JSON data in the in CSV. **I do not want to create a new CSV file but just want to add (Append) few more lines to the existing testfile.csv file without overwriting the file**. May someone please help what to change in the following code to force it to append the file instead of writing a new one? I heard about **StandardOpenOption.APPEND** but no idea where to put that. Thanks

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import com.oracle.e1.common.OrchestrationAttributes;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

HashMap < String, Object > main(OrchestrationAttributes orchAttr, HashMap inputMap) {
HashMap < String, Object > returnMap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
returnMap.put("CSVComplete", "false");
// Write the view number after jsonIn.fs_DATABROWSE_
def jsonIn = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputMap.get("Vendor Data"));
def jsonData = jsonIn.fs_DATABROWSE_GettingJsonDataFromSomewhere.data.gridData.rowset;

if (jsonData.size() == 0) {
  returnMap.put("CSVComplete", "empty");
  return returnMap;
}
def fileName = orchAttr.getTempFileName("testfile.csv");
returnMap.put("CSVOutFileName", fileName);
//class writer to write file def
def sw = new StringWriter();
//build the CSV writer with a header
//def csv = new CSVPrinter(sw, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("Business Unit", "Document Number", "LT", "SUB","Amount","HardcodedTHREAD","ApprovedBudget","fromview003"));
  def csv = new CSVPrinter(sw, CSVFormat.DEFAULT); //No header
// create output file
fileCsvOut = new File(fileName);
def count=0;
// build the CSV
def an8Map = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.size(); i++) {
  def businessunit = jsonData[i].table1_column1;
   if (an8Map.contains(businessunit)) {
     continue;
   }
   an8Map.add(businessunit);
   count++;
   csv.printRecord(businessunit, jsonData[i].table_column,  
                   jsonData[i].table1_column1, jsonData[i]. table1_column2, jsonData[i]. table1_column3, "Fixed text1 "Fixed text2", "Fixedtext3");
}
csv.close();

//writing csv to file
fileCsvOut.withWriter('UTF-8') {
  writer ->
   writer.write(sw.toString()) 
}
orchAttr.writeDebug(sw.toString());
returnMap.put("csv", sw.toString());
returnMap.put("CSVComplete", "true");
returnMap.put("CSVcount", Integer.toString(count));
return returnMap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `withWriterAppend` instead of `withWriter`

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withWriterAppend(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: This is super perfect, many thanks daggett!